# How I can Join this 3 Tables with JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I want to join these 3 Tables.
[image]

Here you see my Person Entity

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Person", schema = "public")

public class PatientEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String name;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "person_contact", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id") })
@Column(name = "contact")
private Set<ContactEntity> contacts;
//Getter Setters
```

And here is my contact entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contact",schema="public")
public class ContactEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
//Getter Setters
```

I just read the Persons from the Table with findById with a Spring JPARepository, but there is no Contact mapped. There is no error during my HTTP request, but instead of a Contact there is null and this error message:
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.

The business case is, that every Person can have one or more contact. Is it possible to make it with JPA Annotations or do I need to map it by myself with a JPQL? Or should I create an Entity for the middle table? (person_contact)

The Database is a PostgreSQL Database.
There is this notification too in the Log:

```
ERROR: column contacts0_.contacts_id does not exist
  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "contacts0_.contact_id".
  Position: 306
```

Comment: Why  you did not mapped person to contact (oneToMany)?

Comment: inverseJoinColumns looks fishy. Try contact_id instead of id. On top of that, reconsider dB change to avoid join table.

Comment: @esprittn must it be? or is this only if I want to know which contact is for which person?

Comment: @Lesiak DB changes are not possible,  If I change it to  "contact_id" there is this failure message: Unable to find column with logical name: contact_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(public.contact) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@JoinTable` has incorrect `@JoinColumn` specifications and corresponds to the following ddl.

```
create table person_contact (person_id bigint not null, contacts_id bigint not null, primary key (person_id, contacts_id))
```

To map your db structure, use following (note removed `@Column` annotation)

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "person_contact", joinColumns =
        {
                @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        })
private Set<ContactEntity> contacts;
```

I also encourage you to read https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ and reconsider a db structure without a join table (depending on your load and the effort to make this db change)